# Kinetic energy during 1 minute - wrong?

Tags: energy, mass, rotational-dynamics

I've come across this IEEE paper whilst researching for a project I've undertaken regarding a bicycle generator. This paper concerns an exercise bike powered electric generator. Essentially they have stated:

For a $10\,\mathrm{kg}$, $40\,\mathrm{cm}$ diameter flywheel they can determine the kinetic energy of the flywheel during 1 minute:

$$K = \frac{1}{2}mr^2w^2 = 0.2 \times  10 \times 0.2^2 \times 264^2$$

They have assumed $$w = 264rpm$$

I know that $$w = (rpm \times \frac{pi}{30})^2$$

which equals $$764.30$$ not $$69696$$ but that's not the problem

Where did $1\ \mathrm{ minute}$ come from? How is it involved? I'm sure this isn't the correct way to calculate this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Note: paper can be found here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmxtd9tswcqm94x/Strzelecki%20bike%20generator%20IEEE%20paper%202007.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Was the rotation frequency perhaps expressed in RPM (common in engineering problems)?

Comment: Is the source available on the web?

Comment: I think this is a misprint or possibly a mistranslation (I note the authors are Polish so English isn't their first language). Searching the pdf for the word *during* reveals several other apparently incomprehensible uses of the term.

Answer (score 1):

Their paper is inconsistent.  They filled in $\omega = 264$ with the other quantities in SI units, so ω should be expressed in rad/s (often written $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$).  So they assumed ω was already in rad/s.  If they say they assumed $\omega = 264~\mathrm{rpm}$, that's not consistent with the values they plugged in.

Your value of 69696 is hard to decipher without a label or units.  It looks like $264^2$, which makes me think you mean $\omega^2 = 69696~\mathrm{(rad/s)^2}$.  That is consistent with their calculation.

For that specific kinetic energy calculation, the 1 minute is irrelevant.  Kinetic energy is an instantaneous quantity and they're not talking about the rate of change (i.e. power).  It could be constant for a minute, increase from zero to a final value, or decrease from an initial value to zero.  The minute could be useful in determining the rotational speed (if you counted the rotations), but once ω is known, K is simple to find.

Their next calculation is confusing, because the kinetic energy of the wheel is irrelevant when trying to figure out the amount of energy one can extract from the bike.  The kinetic energy of the wheel will be roughly constant, and the energy input (from the rider) will equal the energy extracted (to the generator).  It's the rider that is more important in determining the available generated energy, not the wheel.